# How to extract very large xml data and store in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, dictionary, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file named `Comments.xml` which has a size of 15 GB. I want to obtain a dictionary with 2 keys i.e., `UserId` and `Text`. Note that there are many missing values for `UserId` and `Text` in the file. I tried the following code but because the file size is too large the RAM (13 GB RAM) crashes. Is there an efficient way to obtain the data from the xml file for data analysis?

**Part of xml file `Comments.xml`**

```
<comments>
<row Id = '1' UserId = '143' Text = 'Hello World'>
<row Id = '2' UserId = '183' Text = 'Trigonometry is important.'>
<row Id = '3' UserId = '5645' Text = 'Mathematics is best.'>
<row Id = '4' UserId = '143' Text = 'Hello stack overflow'>
<row Id = '5' UserId = '143' Text = 'Hello'>
```

**Code**

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.iterparse('Comments.xml')

comments = {} #Dictionary to store the required data

for event, root in tree:

  if (('Text' in root.attrib) and ('UserId' in root.attrib)): #To check for missing values
    Text = root.attrib['Text']
    UserId = root.attrib['UserId']
    userid_comments.update({UserId:Text}) #Adding data to dictionary
    root.clear()
```

**Expected Output**

```
{'143':'Hello World','183':'Trigonometry is important.','5645':'Mathematics is best.','143':'Hello stack overflow','143':'Hello'}

OR

{'UserId':['143','183','5645','143','143'],'Text':['Hello World','Trigonometry is important.','Mathematics is best.','Hello stack overflow','Hello']}
```

Comment: what is the output you are getting with your code and how it differs from expected output?

Comment: and also the xml you posted is not valid `row` tag is not ended

Comment: Are you familiar with [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)?

Comment: dictionary doesn't have duplicate keys. your expected output is invalid

Comment: @deadshot I have added the expected output, you may help me with whichever output you feel will be more useful for data analysis. Also I have just shown the first 5 lines of the xml file so I have not closed the root tag. The original xml file is valid and this code works fine for smaller xml files.

Comment: @JacobIRR I have not used generators.

Comment: @deadshot I had originally tried to store the data in a dataframe but because of the large file size the RAM crashed so I tried it with a dictionary, you are right a dictionary cannot have duplicate keys. Can you suggest how the required data can be obtained without using a dataframe or dictionary?

Comment: @Subhawna your problem is a perfect time to learn generators. Instead of putting massive amounts of data into memory, you can just `yield` things as needed

Comment: how exactly are you trying to use this values so someone can help

Comment: @JacobIRR I am relatively new to coding in Python, can you please help me with the code. Additionally I had been advised to use `pickle` to do this. Is it useful?

Comment: @deadshot The 'UserId' in the xml file is divided into 3 classes (Gold, Silver and Bronze) whose values are stored in 3 separate lists(That are provided apart from the xml file). I have to create a word counter to find the words with highest frequency for each of these 3 classes. I know how to do this with dataframes but not with xml files.

Comment: create a new file with `UserId` and `Text` values, then you can use pandas

Comment: @deadshot I am quite new to Python, can you please provide the code snippet in the answer.

Comment: pickle will not help with the memory problem

Comment: Then how to proceed @JacobIRR ?

Comment: You're going to need to spend some time learning how generators work and then apply what you learn to the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
import io
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

def getComments(fileName):
    comments = {'UserId': [], 'Text': []}
    with io.open(fileName, "r", encoding='utf-8') as file:
        line = file.readline()  # Read data line by line
        while line != '':
            doc = SimplifiedDoc(line)  # Instantiate a doc
            row = doc.getElement('row')  # Get row
            if row:
                comments['UserId'].append(row['UserId'])
                comments['Text'].append(row['Text'])
            line = file.readline()
    return comments
comments = getComments('Comments.xml')  # This dictionary will be very large, too
```

Here are more examples: https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Answer (score 0):

See below.

This will **NOT** going to solve your RAM issue. In order to solve the RAM issue you need to use SAX:

> Simple API for XML (SAX) − Here, you register callbacks for events of interest and then let the parser proceed through the document. This is useful when your documents are large or you have memory limitations, it parses the file as it reads it from disk and the entire file is never stored in memory.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

xml = '''<comments>
<row Id = "1" UserId = "143" Text = "Hello World"/>
<row Id = "2" UserId = "183" Text = "Trigonometry is important."/>
<row Id = "3" UserId = "5645" Text = "Mathematics is best."/>
<row Id = "4" UserId = "143" Text = "Hello stack overflow"/>
<row Id = "5" UserId = "143" Text = "Hello"/></comments>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for row in root.findall('.//row'):
    user_id = row.attrib.get('UserId')
    text = row.attrib.get('Text')
    if user_id is not None and text is not None:
        data[user_id].append(text)
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'143': ['Hello World', 'Hello stack overflow', 'Hello'], '183': ['Trigonometry is important.'], '5645': ['Mathematics is best.']})
```